# Air leaking from rear tire

Tags: wheels, tire-pressure

The rear tyre pressure of my motorbike gets reduced from 36 psi to 23 psi within a week. I checked, there is no puncture or any problems with the nozzle. The temperature conditions where i live are also normal between 28-35 degree celsius.

Is it a possibility that the air may leaking from the rim?

Comment: When you say "... or any problems with the nozzle." ... are you talking about the valve stem? If so, what have you done to ensure there's no issue with the valve stem? Is your motorcycle tire tubeless?

Comment: What bike? What are the rims made of? Some rims can become porous...

Answer (score 1):

You can determine the source of the leak by filling the tire to the normal pressure and applying soapy water with a spray bottle or even an ordinary paint brush. The soap will not damage the tire or rim and when applied to an area that is leaking air, will bubble up to show the region of the leak.

Your tire valve can leak at the rim edge, but also can leak internally at the valve mechanism. If your rim is damaged but not easily seen, the bubbles will grow at that portion of the wheel.

Do not discount either the possibility of a "filled puncture" in the tread area. Apply the soapy water to all of the tire and wheel to ensure you don't miss a section.

You can inflate beyond recommended pressure to have even more force behind the leak, but remember to return the air pressure to normal when the testing is completed. I was unable to locate a safety factor regarding over-inflation, although I have in the past inflated a 45 psi tire to about 60 with little problems or danger.

Comment: putting the wheel / tire in a big tank is much easier... just need the tank - the bath can be good, but make sure it is clean after...

Comment: I agree that's an option, but I'd prefer to use a spray bottle, especially if it's a rear wheel that would require much adjustment and finesse after re-installing.

Comment: If the rim proves to be porous, then it will need those adjustments anyway...

Comment: It's not a puncture. That i have already got checked. If it's the rim, how it can be repaired? @SolarMike My bike is of Honda, tubeless tires - Pirelli.

Comment: A porous rim can sometimes be made non-porous by removing the tire, and covering the rim's inside surface with sealant. But if the rim hasn't leaked previously (and hasn't been physically damaged), it's much less likely than that the leak is actually from a puncture in the tire which you haven't yet located, or from a defective valve or valve/rim connection.  Go after it all with soapy water as fred_dot_u suggests and report back.

Comment: Check the value, the value has a tiny washer on it, it simply unscrews